# MySQL date format sort error

Tags: php, mysql, date

desc or asc date for sorting query fails :(

How am I supposed to mSQL query?

Please could you help?

```
$tours = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tours WHERE tour_category_id='".$tour_category_id[category_id]."' AND tour_status='Aktif' ORDER BY kayit_tarihi DESC ");
```

Comment: Could you try `$tour_category_id['category_id']` ?

Comment: did you get any error?

Comment: To sort by the highest date. Error: Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in tours.php on line 81

Comment: Date format : 2014-02-20

Comment: What is kayit_tarihi? Is that the date? What format does it has? Why do you order by this field?

Answer (score 0):

```
  $someVariable =  $tour_category_id[category_id];
 $tours = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tours WHERE tour_category_id='$someVariable' AND tour_status='Aktif' ORDER BY kayit_tarihi DESC ");
```

Try this.

Comment: At least have the decency to comment on top of giving a downvote

Comment: remove space on here '$someVariable '

Answer (score 0):

```
$tours = mysql_query("SELECT * 
                      FROM tours 
                      WHERE tour_category_id='".$tour_category_id[category_id]."' 
                        AND tour_status='Aktif' 
                      ORDER BY tour_category_id DESC ");
```

Answer (score 0):

change `$tour_category_id[category_id]` to `$tour_category_id["category_id"]`